# Is using double parenthesis math posix compliant?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, posix

This simple script runs with `/bin/sh` interpreter:

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash

fac=1

for i in $(seq 1 $1); do
    fac=$((fac*i))
done
echo "The factoriral of $1 is $fac"
```

But I would like to know why it works, when there is `$((math))` in it. I thought it is the only feature of `/bin/bash` not `/bin/sh`. So what will definitely *not* work in `/bin/sh` but works in `/bin/bash`?

Comment: `$((...))` is standard. Beware however that not all *operators* are standard -- this will work "fine" in both bash and dash, but will NOT increment the `i` variable in dash: `i=3; : $((++i)); echo $i`

Comment: Also, on some systems `/bin/sh` is actually bash, and bash will NOT disable its language extensions when invoked as `/bin/sh`.

Comment: @user414777 so how to `((i++))` in dash? I use that quite a lot and would like to make compatible

Comment: `i=$((i+1))`, `: $((i=i+1))`.

Comment: this works in dash `: $((i+=1))`

Comment: The question is asking about `sh` without specifying either the operating system or what the program denoted by `sh` is.  _People cannot tell you about the behaviour of `sh`, or compare it with something else, unless you tell them what `sh` is._  `sh` is commonly five different programs on different operating systems, and can possibly be one of a lot more.  _You must tell people your operating system and what `sh` is._  No: "Linux" is a kernel, not an operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$((math expression))` feature is a POSIX feature and supported by all modern POSIX compliant shells.

POSIX however does not standardize path names and for this reason POSIX calls it unspecified what happens when you call `/bin/sh`

This is why POSIX did not standardize `#! /bin/sh` eiter...

There are UNIX versions that offer an old Bourne Shell if you call `/bin/sh`. All Solaris versions up to Solaris-10 come with an old Bourne Shell in `/bin/sh`that does not support `$((math expression))`. These Solaris versions are still certified for POSIX compliance. There are other operating systems with different shell types (POSIX or non-POSIX).

Linux e.g. typically comes with either `bash` or `dash` in `/bin/sh`. `dash` only delivers basic POSIX compatibility, not sufficient for a POSIX platform that is permitted to be called **UNIX** since it does not support multi byte charcters. `bash` on Linux is also not fully compliant for a **UNIX** system as (on Linux) it is compiled in a way that results in a non-compliant `echo` builtin  by default.

BTW: if you like to get a POSIX compliant shell on a POSIX certified platform, you need to call:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH`
export PATH
sh
```

This works because `getconf PATH` is required to return a PATH setup where POSIX compliant variants of the programs are found first.

In other words: if you have a shell script that starts with `#!/bin/sh`, it is not granted that `$((math expression))` will work. What actually happens, depends on the platform you run it on. Even if a shell is POSIX compliant, only the basic math expresions from C are required to work. `$((i++))` is e.g. not granted to work on a shell that has been certified for POSIX compliance.

What shell is actually in a specific path name can be checked by running:

```
$shell whatshell.sh
```

fetch `whatshell.sh` from [https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/whatshell/)